# Android Studio AVD Not Starting

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I recently updated android studio to **version 0.9.9** and now my AVD machines are not starting. I get a grey box that pops up for half a second with a status bar and a button that says "background" and on the bottom log it says "C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_2".

In the previous android studio version I was able to run the machines and apps inside them with no problem, but after the update it does not work.

I tried several solutions I read on other threads and none of them worked, since I already had the path set up from my previous set up.

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade studio to 1.x and  maybe integrate genymotion to android studio.

http://ngotuongdan.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/gia-lap-android-voi-genymotion/ help install genymotion

Answer (score 0):

New updated android studio version is available now. I updated my android studio and the nexus emulator is working. Find the menu  Help->Check for update in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Updating and installing HAXM (through the sdk manager, then navigating to the .exe location) solved my problem.